# pandas select specific groups

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe with an ID column and a measurement column

```
ID measurement
1 A
1 B
1 C
1 D
2 A
2 B
2 C
2 D
3 A
4 A
4 B
4 C
4 D
4 E
```

I want to select only rows which have full measurements (A-D) per ID and remove rows which either have fewer (for example ID 3) or more measurements (for example ID 4) per ID.

Is there an efficient way to achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
In [92]: df.groupby('ID').filter(lambda x: set(x['measurement']) == set('ABCD'))
Out[92]:
   ID measurement
0   1           A
1   1           B
2   1           C
3   1           D
4   2           A
5   2           B
6   2           C
7   2           D
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `transform`

```
In [1001]: df[df.groupby('ID')['measurement'].transform(lambda x: set(x) == set('ABCD'))]
Out[1001]:
   ID measurement
0   1           A
1   1           B
2   1           C
3   1           D
4   2           A
5   2           B
6   2           C
7   2           D
```